# Material-UI autocomplete single select is not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to build a autocomplete text field, with a single select. I am using typescript, material-ui, react.

Here is my code:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="tags-outlined-t"
  options={data}
  getOptionLabel={(option: string) => option}
  defaultValue={value}
  filterSelectedOptions
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="City" />
  )}
  onChange={onChange}
  className={styles.select}
  classes={classes}
/>
```

I am using `"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.53"`. and getting following error.

> Type '{ id: string; options: string[]; getOptionLabel: (option: string) => string; defaultValue: string[] | undefined; filterSelectedOptions: true; renderInput: (params: RenderInputParams) => Element; onChange: (event: any, value: string[] | null) => void; className: string; classes: Record<...>; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & AutocompleteProps & UseAutocompleteSingleProps) | (IntrinsicAttributes & AutocompleteProps<...> & UseAutocompleteMultipleProps<...>)'.
> Property 'multiple' is missing in type '{ id: string; options: string[]; getOptionLabel: (option: string) => string; defaultValue: string[] | undefined; filterSelectedOptions: true; renderInput: (params: RenderInputParams) => Element; onChange: (event: any, value: string[] | null) => void; className: string; classes: Record<...>; }' but required in type 'UseAutocompleteMultipleProps'.

Can anyone help? What I am missing. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide more info, at least more complete code, it is rather difficult to reproduce. Error message is hard to read as well

Comment: `Property 'multiple' is missing`, `UseAutocompleteMultipleProps` requires `multiple` as tsc determine it is `UseAutocompleteMultipleProps`. Maybe you have some props that is incompatible with all other types. check the type of your `defaultValue`, `value` and `onChange`. It is hard to tell without knowing the actual type and looking into a reproducible snippet.

Comment: @seanplwong thanks!. VSCode was showing the wrong error that's why I got confused. Actually, there is a type mismatch for defaultValue.

Comment: let's give more detail in the question and come up with some conclusion so that people who stumble upon this post will have a better idea